# Sending a stream to a .Net WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, wcf

I have to access a .Net WCF Service from a desktop application. Basically I need to pass some data entered in a textbox. However the data can not be passed in raw format. And there's no way change the method on Web Service side since its client/third party service.

Method signature is as follows
Stream ProcessStream(Stream request);

The only thing I came to know regarding whats done to the stream is as followed.

```
        HandleRequestHeaders();
        XmlDocument reqDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument resDoc = new XmlDocument();

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"] == null || !Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"]))
        {
            Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
            inStream.CopyTo(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            try
            {
                reqDoc.Load(ms);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

So basically I need to send an xml document pasted/entered in a textbox of a desktop application.

Comment: y dont u send it just like a string or xelement.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Like I said its third party and there's no way I can change it !

Comment: I tried to send MemoryStream  wcfClient1.ProcessRequest(GetStream()); However I get an issue If I do that.